# How to say with one word: "it has a tree structure"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, adjectives

- When objects relate to each other as pearls on a string (open, not closed), then we can say that the whole structure is "sequential" or "linear".
- The same way, we can call something "cyclic" if its elements are sequential, and the first is also connected to the last, like a necklace.

But is there a single adjective for expressing that some objects form a tree structure, like:

[image]

My only idea was "hierarchical", but that also implies that the root (starting point) of the tree is the most, and leaves are the least important, which isn't always the case.

Comment: "Tree-structured"?

Comment: Sure looks like a directed acyclic graph to me, with the added restriction that children can have but one parent not many.

Comment: Perhaps "branched"?

Comment: I believe the term for this type of relational diagram is a "Parse tree". So I believe the term would be parsing or branching

Comment: I intentionally didn't use expressions from graph theory, because I search for a non-scientific one.

Comment: My immediate thought was _furcating_ generically (the particular kind of tree structure you show here would more specifically be _bifurcating_), but I'm not really sure if people in general would understand that to refer to this kind of structure.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks, I've never heard of that word, but looks applicable in many cases.

Comment: *tree-like*, *tree-shaped*, *arboreal*

Comment: What do the numbers represent?  Sequence?

Comment: Also, if you're specifically talking about graphs, you can simply call it a [*tree*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)).

Comment: I think "hierarchical" is still OK, despite the implications of importance - after all the "top" node in your diagram is generally called the "root" and the "bottom" nodes are "leaves". Tree structures *are* hierarchical :)

Comment: Yep, I'm used to hearing XML described as hierarchical and I don't think it denotes importance.

Comment: Another one who was about to post hierarchy as an answer, as there's no implications of importance when talking about structure... "any system of persons or things ranked one above another." - the one above another is the key for me.

Comment: @tchrist The concepts "children" and "parents" don't exist for general graphs. If you speak about "children" and "parents", you are automatically talking about trees. Therefore, a child can actually never have more than one parent because that's the way a tree is structured.

Comment: @thomj1332 Probably, that's the most common meaning when you see numbers on a tree structure like this.

Comment: @PV22 It is possibly a parsing tree, but what you mean when you say that is that it is possibly generated from parsing an expression. Parsing is the linguistic activity, even when applied to computer languages.

Comment: "treeish!"  (this is a joke only OTTers will get. (see xkcd/1190) )

Comment: Hidden lizard? Sorry, just LOL-ing at your user name. :-)

Comment: @HelloGoodbye a family tree is an obvious counter example.

Comment: @MartinSmith I would guess that OP is considering [this kind trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)) as he/she is using a fairly technical language, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @Drew "Arboreal" should be in an answer, and it isn't yet. Won't you put one up?

Comment: @Conrado: Done...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Dendritic**

> branching like a tree

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dendritic)

Comment: +1 If in doubt, Greek beats Latin

Comment: The OP wants to say "it has a tree structure" in one word. "It is dendritic" is three words. I don't think the single word "dendritic" can replace "it has a tree structure".

Comment: @bof how would this be different from his _sequential_ and  _linear_ examples?

Comment: That will be sure to confuse people.

Comment: As interesting and accurate as this word is, it is pretty rare and will most likely not be understood.

Comment: Dendritic is a useful word. There are lots of different examples in many different fields: https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&biw=1215&bih=680&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=dendritic&oq=dendritic&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l4.14873.15892.0.16851.4.4.0.0.0.0.134.507.0j4.4.0....0...1..64.psy-ab..0.4.504...0i67k1.oMxURO2QAlM

Comment: It's used in biology and geology, but not in mathematics or computer science so far as I know.

Comment: @dangph Hits Graph theory: https://www.google.com/search?num=20&safe=off&q=dendritic+graph+theory&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_u6rZkaPVAhWDez4KHTjUALMQvwUIJCgA&biw=1215&bih=680 - Math and Comp Sci. Physics: https://www.google.com/search?num=20&safe=off&biw=1215&bih=680&q=dendritic+physics&oq=dendritic+physics&gs_l=psy-ab.3...124633.126742.0.127012.7.7.0.0.0.0.213.901.0j5j1.6.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.5.778...0j0i22i30k1j33i160k1.lj7Qiu89Wxo Chemistry: https://www.google.com/search?num=20&safe=off&q=dendritic+chemistry&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkzJS9kqPVAhWGNj4KHQgTDksQvwUIJCgA&biw=1215&bih=680

Comment: The first link on the first search was to Wolfram, which said: "In continuum theory, a dendrite is a locally connected continuum that contains no simple closed curve. A semicircle is therefore a dendrite, while a triangle is not." So it would appear that _dendrite_ has a very particular meaning in mathematics and isn't used to mean _tree-like_ in general.

Comment: It's pretty particular in neuroanatomy too: http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/dendrite. Useful term to know in a *lot* of fields.

Comment: This is the only viable alternative to "branching", and that has more problems when using in sentences, e.g. one can confuse it with a verb. I would like to see "dendritic" become a standard word in IT too.

Answer (score 46):

You can call it "tree-like." Alternatively, you could describe it as "branching."

Comment: +1 for an answer in plain English that will get the image across to most people, assuming many don't know enough Greek or Latin to decipher what "arboromorphic" or "dendritic" means (or at least need some time to stop and think about it).

Answer (score 10):

Try **arborescent**:

> resembling a tree in properties, growth, structure, or appearance

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arborescent)

Comment: "Arboromorphic" may work, too.

Comment: Arborescent structure is also the term Gilles Deleuze uses for the opposite of rhizomatic structure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arborescent

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: Surely [arboriform](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arboriform)?

Answer (score 6):

I like the term ***[ramified](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ramified)*** (2, 3 - Free Dictionary) to describe something that develops into a branching or tree-like structure.

Comment: Interesting.  Unfortunately, I think the massive popularity of sense (1) in that definition is so overwhelming that most readers will think of it first even if they are aware of the other senses (and as a reader with a lot of background working with mathematical-type trees, I've never heard this word used to describe them, so suspect it is very likely to not be understood)

Comment: Note that [ramified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramification_(mathematics)) already has a mathematical definition, which is a lot more specific than what the OP is going for.

Answer (score 4):

Some people find it surprising that any (connected) **acyclic** structure can be treated as a tree, and even more surprising that any node in a given (connected) acyclic structure can be treated as the root node of a tree.

Often "hierarchical" has the connotations that there is one special privileged root node that is most important, and leaves are the least important.

When that connotation is unwanted, people often use the adjective "acyclic".
There isn't anything special or more important about any one node in an acyclic graph, because *every* node works fine as a root node.

A few authors use "tree" as a synonym for any connected acyclic graph.
Those authors use **free tree** or **unrooted tree** that does not yet have a root.
Later, after a root node has been arbitrarily chosen, the structure becomes a "rooted tree".

> A connected **acyclic** graph is known as a tree, and a possibly
>   disconnected acyclic graph is known as a forest (i.e., a collection of
>   trees). -- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AcyclicGraph.html

and

> A tree is a set of straight line segments connected at their ends containing no closed loops (cycles). In other words, it is a simple,
>   undirected, connected, acyclic graph (or, equivalently, a connected
>   forest). A tree with n nodes has n-1 graph edges. Conversely, a
>   connected graph with n nodes and n-1 edges is a tree.
>   Trees with no particular [root] node singled out are sometimes called **free trees** (or **unrooted tree**), by way of distinguishing them from rooted trees. -- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tree.html

There are many practical situations that involve some some possibly-cyclic connected graph, and a variety of algorithms have been developed to cut cycles (if any) until only the [minimum spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/minimum_spanning_tree) remains -- a connected acyclic graph.

After a (connected) acyclic graph is built, one person can arbitrarily pick *any* node as the root node, and treat the rest of the acyclic structure as a tree, with all the nodes directly connected to the chosen root node as the children of that root node, then all the remaining nodes directly connected to those children as the grandchildren of that root node, and so on for every level of descendants.
A different person can arbitrarily pick some *other* node of that same acyclic graph as the root node, and use the same algorithm to build another rooted tree that is arranged differently than the first person's tree.

Answer (score 2):

*tree-like*, *tree-shaped*, or *arboreal*.

---

> Adjective: arboreal  aa(r)'bo-ree-ul
>
> Of or relating to or formed by trees
>
> "an arboreal roof";
>
> - arborical, arborary, arborous
>
> Inhabiting or frequenting trees
>
> "arboreal apes";
>
> - arboreous, tree-living
>
> Resembling a tree in form and branching structure
>
> "arboreal coral found off the coast of Bermuda";
>
> - arboreous, arborescent, arboresque, arboriform, dendriform, dendroid, dendroidal, treelike, tree-shaped

-- [WordWeb](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=arboreal)

Answer (score -5):

One adjective many would find acceptable is fractal. One dictionary definition, "a curve or geometric figure, each part of which has the same statistical character as the whole."

Comment: There are implications here that are probably not wanted.  Fractal in common usage usually implies "infinitely detailed", which would only be true of an infinitely large tree.  Also, in technical use, it means "having a fractal dimension" or "non-integral [capacity dimension](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CapacityDimension.html)" which is definitely not true of trees.